# Dynamics CRM is ignoring the default value for two-option field

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

Quick question.

I have a custom two-option field on an entity, with "Yes"/"No" as the values; "Yes" has the underlying value 1, while "No" has the underlying value 0. I've set the default value for this field to "Yes". However, when I create new entity records, the field always gets the value "No" (0 in the database). It seems to be ignoring the default value I've set. Why?

The field is not present on any of the entity forms, as it's only used in underlying plugin code. Should that matter?

Answer (score 0):

Are you creating a new record for this entity using code that uses the strongly-typed objects? If so, when you create a "new" entity in code, I'm guessing the class itself is setting that field to "false" by default. I don't think those generated classes respect the default values in the metadata. I also think that *all* fields are submitted on a create when you use these generated classes. That means that your class is setting it to "no" by default and then on create, the system thinks that you explicitly set it to "no" so default values are not applied. I think you need to explicitly remove that attribute from the attribute collection of your entity before you create it. That way the system should respect the default value on create. Sorry for all the "I thinks" but I'm not in a place that I can test or verify all of this. :)

Comment: Thanks, good point! However, I'm not creating the entity records in code - they're created directly in CRM, so it's all standard CRM functionality at that point. We ended up working around the issue by creating a new field with identical settings, and the new field worked as expected with the default value. So it seems like there's some dark sorcery going on somewhere under the surface of the old field.